# Export and Require Issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, export, require

just having an issue exporting and requiring to be able to test. I feel like I've done everything right but I'm missing something super obvious. I'm receiving referenceError: Factorial is not defined (as per the screenshot attached).

Below is my .js file code.

```
const recursive = {}

function factorial(num) {
    if (num <= 1) {
        return num;
    }
}



module.exports = recursive;
```

And below is my test.js file code:

```
const recursive = require("./recursive.js");

describe("factorial", () => {
    test("function returns itself when 1 or less is called", () => {
        const test = 1;

        expect(factorial(test)).toBe(1);

    });

});
```

Can anyone see the obvious mistake I'm making please?

Screenshot of Issue:
[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Comment: I was trying to export the whole .js over to test? And yes, I'm trying to build the function through TDD, the calculation will be implemented as I go through it.

Comment: _"I was trying to export the whole .js over to test"_ The main goal of modules is encapsulation. You have to export the objects you want to import somewhere else. The file is evaluated and the empty `recursive` is exported. The test is mathematically incorrect: 0! = 1 and in general n! = 1 for n <= 1, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial